# Export to PDF with expanded drilldown the report viewer by C #?

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services, reportviewer

How do I export to excel or pdf with all data already expanded (Drill Down) in the report viewer.

Export to PDF for example, the data that are part of the drilldown not appear.

Is there any way to configure it via C #?

Here's a part of my code:

```
byte[] bytes = report.ServerReport.Render("PDF");
string fsFileName = "C:\Reports\MyReport.pdf";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fsFileName, FileMode.Create);
fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
fs.Close();
```

I thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Report viewer loads a report definition language (RDL) file, and can then output the result in the viewer or like you want to do export it to PDF/Word/Excel...

Are you working on a web app? or desktop? anyway [here is a link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654) where you can open and write a PDF file to the browser directly in ASP.NET.